# Sum of number with XSL Transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, sum

I want to calculate the sum of the balance's customer.

This is my XML code:
`<bank>
        <accounts>
            <deposit-accounts>
                <deposit-account id="d1" interesse="0.03">
                    <balance>2500</balance>
                </deposit-account>
                <deposit-account id="d2" interesse="0.03">
                    <balance>15075</balance>
                </deposit-account>
            </deposit-accounts>
          <bank-accounts>
            <bank-account id="c1">
                <balance>4025</balance>
            </bank-account>
            <bank-account id="c2">
                <balance>-125</balance>
            </bank-account>
            <bank-account id="c3">
                <balance>325</balance>
            </bank-account>
        </bank-accounts>
    </accounts>
    <customers>
        <customer>
            <name>Ben Richerdson</name>
            <address>Park Drive 2</address>
            <accounts>
                <bank-account ref="c2" />
                <deposit-account ref="d1" />
                <bank-account ref="c1" />
            </accounts>
        </customer>
    </customers>
</bank>`

And this is my XSL code:
    `<xsl:for-each select="customer">

        <xsl:for-each select="accounts/*">
            <xsl:variable name="account" select="@ref" />
            <xsl:for-each select="/bank/accounts/bank-accounts/bank-account">
                <xsl:if test="@id = $account">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
                    <xsl:value-of select="balance" />
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="/bank/accounts/deposit-accounts/deposit-account">
                <xsl:if test="@id = $account">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
                    <xsl:value-of select="balance" />
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>`

Finally, I want to calculate the balance's total of the customer's accounts. 
In this case I want the results -125 + 4025 + 2500 = 6400 for the customer "Ben Richerdson".
I try with the sum function but the result is -12540252500 (i.e concatenation of string)
Can you help me? 
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a key

```
<xsl:key name="ac" match="bank/accounts/deposit-accounts/deposit-account | bank/accounts/bank-accounts/bank-account" use="@id"/>
```

then you can write

```
<xsl:template match="customer">
  <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('ac', accounts/*/@ref)/balance)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Here is a complete sample:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

<xsl:key name="ac" match="bank/accounts/deposit-accounts/deposit-account | bank/accounts/bank-accounts/bank-account" use="@id"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//customer"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="customer">
  Name: <xsl:value-of select="name"/>, sum:<xsl:value-of select="sum(key('ac', accounts/*/@ref)/balance)"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I run that with Saxon 6.5.5 against your input sample it outputs `Name: Ben Richerdson, sum:6400`.

Comment: Thanks but exists a better or simplier solution? 
Because I don't ever use <xsl:key>. 

THANKS 
REGARDS